# Sequence $\{f_n\}$ of non-neg. meas. on [0,1] s.t $f_n \to 0$ a.e but if $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx =(b-a)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, measurable-functions, sequence-of-function

I need a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of non-negative measurable functions on [0,1]  s.t $f_n \to 0$ a.e but for all $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx =(b-a)$$

I was trying different kinds of indicator functions and still, I can not find the adequate. This is a problem from a past Ph.D. qualifying exam in measure theory that I'm studying for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $g_n = n \cdot \chi_{A_n}$ with $A_n = \bigcup_{k = 0}^{n-1} \bigl[\frac{kn}{n^2}, \frac{kn+1}{n^2}\bigr)$ _almost_ does it. That sequence doesn't converge to $0$ almost everywhere. Can you modify this to get your desired sequence?

Comment: @DanielFischer, 
 
If we remove the $n$
from $g_n$ and remove one of the $n$'s in the numerator and the denominator of each interval that defines $A_n$ I think it will work. I'm right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend. To get it to converge to $0$ almost everywhere, we need to make the support smaller. For example instead of letting each interval have a length of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for a total measure of the support of $\frac{1}{n}$, we can let the intervals have length $\frac{1}{n^3}$ so that the measure of the support is $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Then Borel-Cantelli tells us that we have convergence to $0$ almost everywhere. Making the support smaller, we must scale up the function so that we still have a total mass of $1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Take $$f_n:= 2^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 1_{[k2^{-n},k2^{-n}+4^{-n}]}$$ and consider subintervals of $[0,1]$ whose endpoints are dyadic (why does this suffice?). Also notice that the measure of the set of points where $f$ is nonzero equals $2^{-n}$.

Comment: @RichardClare A dyadic number is one of the form $k2^{-n}$ for some $n,k \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: You mean is sufficient because they are dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @RichardClare Yes, and so intervals with such endpoints generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$.